# Plotly python bubble chart - add text

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I need to add text to a plotly bubble chart with python. I can only get the text attribute to take 1 value per datapoint. However, for each datapoint I need to show two values on the tooltip: its size, and another value. I'm using a list of lists, loosely based on an example [here](https://plot.ly/python/bubble-charts-tutorial/).

This is my code:

```
bubbletext = dfenv[['Max_FZ','Argmax_FZ']] # dataframe with the 2 cols I need for text
bubbletext = bubbletext.values.tolist() # puts the df into list of lists

trace1 = Scatter(
         x=dfenv['X (ft)'],
         y=dfenv['Y (ft)'],
         text=bubbletext,  # here's the problem
         mode='markers',
         marker=Marker(
            size=dfenv['Max_FZ'],
            sizeref= dfenv['Max_FZ'].max() / 1e2**2,
            sizemode='area'
            )
         )
data = Data([trace1])
layout = Layout(showlegend=False)
fig = Figure(data=data)#, layout=layout)
plot_url = py.plot(fig, filename='Envelope_MaxBubblechart')
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can concatenate a new string column for the text of the tooltip as follows:

```
dfenv['text'] = dfenv['Max_FZ'].round(1).astype(str) + 'units' + '<br>at: ' + dfenv['Argmax_FZ']

trace1 = Scatter(
     x=dfenv['X (ft)'],
     y=dfenv['Y (ft)'],
     text=dfenv['text'], #string df column here with line breaks if needed
     mode='markers',
     marker=Marker(
        size=dfenv['Max_FZ'],
        sizeref= dfenv['Max_FZ'].max() / 1e2**2,
        sizemode='area'
        )
     )
data = Data([trace1])
fig = Figure(data=data)
plot_url = py.plot(fig, filename='Envelope_MaxBubblechart')
```